# GMP's mpz_init_set_str is causing realloc error

Tags: c, gmp

I am working on a project using gmp to implement a basic DH exchange. There are two main functions in this exchange, one to create a public key from the private key, and one to generate the shared secret with a private key and public key.

During the first function, my calls into the gmp lib work as expected. During the second function, my mpz_init_set_str call either causes a seg fault, or an abort with a message saying

realloc(): invalid old size
Aborted (core dumped)

or

malloc.c:2868: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (GLRO (dl_pagesize) - 1)) == 0' failed.

The line causing this is used verbatim in the first function and I am unable to figure out what is causing this.

Below is a sample program that demonstrates the issue when run on my machine. 
I am using gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0. and libgmp10 version 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "gmp.h"
#include "time.h"

#define SECRET_KEY_SIZE             64
#define PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE            512

#define DH_KEY_EXCHANGE_P "96C99B60C4F823707B47A848472345230C5B25103DC37412A701833E8FF5C567A53A41D0B37B10F0060D50F4131C57CF1FD11B6A6CB958F36B1E7D878A4C4BC7"
#define DH_KEY_EXCHANGE_G "2C900DF142E2B839E521725585A92DC0C45D6702A48004A917F74B73DB26391F20AEAE4C6797DD5ABFF0BFCAECB29554248233B5E6682CE1C73DD2148DED76C3"

#define BASE_HEX            16
#define BASE_RADIX          32

char intToCharBase32(int input)
{
    char ret = 0;
    if(input <= 9)
    {
        ret = '0' + input;
    }
    else if(input < 32)
    {
        ret = (input - 10) + 'A';
    }
    return ret;
}

void generateRandomKey(char *random_number_buffer, int len)
{
    short int n;
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        n = rand() % BASE_RADIX;
        random_number_buffer[i] = intToCharBase32(n);
    }
    random_number_buffer[len] = '\0';
}

void calculateDHPublicKey(char *public_key, char *private_key)
{
    mpz_t p;
    mpz_t g;
    mpz_t b;
    mpz_t B;

    mpz_init (B);
    mpz_init_set_str (p, DH_KEY_EXCHANGE_P, BASE_HEX);
    mpz_init_set_str (g, DH_KEY_EXCHANGE_G, BASE_HEX);
    mpz_init_set_str (b, private_key, BASE_RADIX);

    mpz_powm (B, g, b, p);

    mpz_get_str(public_key, BASE_RADIX, B);

    mpz_clear (p);
    mpz_clear (g);
    mpz_clear (b);
    mpz_clear (B);
}

void calculateDHSharedSecret(unsigned char *dh_key_buffer, char *own_private_key, char *other_public_key)
{
    mpz_t p;
    mpz_t b;
    mpz_t A;
    mpz_t SS;

    mpz_init (SS);
    mpz_init_set_str (p, DH_KEY_EXCHANGE_P, BASE_HEX); // <--This line crashes
    mpz_init_set_str (b, own_private_key, BASE_RADIX);
    mpz_init_set_str (A, other_public_key, BASE_RADIX);

    mpz_powm (SS, A, b, p);

    size_t size = 0;

    //todo: move this to the right place (add leading zeros as needed);
    mpz_export(dh_key_buffer, &size, 1, -1, 0, 0, SS);

    mpz_clear (p);
    mpz_clear (b);
    mpz_clear (A);
    mpz_clear (SS);
}

int main (){

    char* private_key = malloc(sizeof(char) * (PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE / BASE_RADIX + 2));
    generateRandomKey(private_key, PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE / BASE_RADIX);
    fprintf(stderr, "Private Key: %s\n", private_key);

    //step 2: generate public key
    char* public_key = malloc(sizeof(char) * (2048 / BASE_RADIX + 1));
    calculateDHPublicKey(public_key, private_key);

    //step 3: share the public key
    fprintf(stderr, "Public Key: %s\n", public_key);

    //step 4: Calculate shared secret
    unsigned char* sharedSecret = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * SECRET_KEY_SIZE);
    memset(sharedSecret, 0, SECRET_KEY_SIZE);

    char* other_pk = "1";
    //for debugging just use 1 as the other side of dh handshake
    calculateDHSharedSecret(sharedSecret, private_key, other_pk);

    //step 5: release resources
    free(private_key);
    free(public_key);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to use mpz_init and then mpz_set_str instead of the mpz_init_set_str and the function still aborts.

I was able to use mpz_init2 and provide an inital size as a workaround, but later in my project, I will not know the size required and would like to avoid having to determine it as an extra step.

(I am well aware that there is much better ways to generate random keys, and rand() is cryptographically insecure, but this project is going to be used to demonstrate this as well as other security issues that are commonly found)

Comment: Have you run it through valgrind?

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition. Multiplying by it is pointless.

Comment: Why are you including standard headers with `"..."` instead of `<...>`?

Comment: As Shawn suggested, valgrind will tell you which buffers are too small.

Comment: Sizeof(char) is 1, yes, but this is being used for educational purposes, the * 1 will be optimized out, and taking every chance to remind students to multiply by the correct size is worth the extra characters.

Comment: I should not be using "" for standard headers. This is not the cause of this issue however.

Comment: I see several sets of output like the following
```==4219== Invalid write of size 1


==4219==    at 0x4E72BDA: __gmpn_get_str (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2)


==4219==    by 0x4E554B7: __gmpz_get_str (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2)

==4219==    by 0x108C4F: calculateDHPublicKey (main.c:56)

==4219==    by 0x108DDB: main (main.c:97)

==4219==  Address 0x54ae0e1 is 0 bytes after a block of size 65 alloc'd

==4219==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==4219==    by 0x108DC4: main (main.c:96)
```

Comment: To me this looks like the error is occurring inside the gmp library.

Comment: The error is telling you that you gave `mpz_get_str` a buffer that is too small to write the whole string. You can just pass 0 to let GMP allocate it with the right size.